# Integrate Video Frame in Tkinter(python)

Tags: python, tkinter, vlc

I am trying to integrate the Video Frame for playing Video Files into the Tk Main window for my project at: [github.com](https://github.com/amanjosan2008/Video-Collection-Manager).
Currently it is launching native VLC Player using subprocess However I want to have an integrated window for the same.

When I execute below code:

```
import vlc
root = Tk()

instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_player_new()
media = instance.media_new("big.mp4")
player.set_media(media)
player.play()

canvas = Canvas(player).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I get this error:
    `AttributeError: 'MediaPlayer' object has no attribute 'tk'`

I tried to get inputs form this GitHub project: [github.com](https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/master/examples/tkvlc.py).
However I was unsuccessful to get it working.

The video currently launches in another window when I remove the Canvas related code. Please advice what is wrong with the code.

Comment: You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43108443/7850929) answer for video frame in tkinter

Comment: I am trying to use this code, thanks for pointing out the link..